# Column based on header in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]
The formula:

```
=IF(RC[2]=""Debit"",RC[-1],IF(RC[2]=""Credit"",-RC[-1]))
```

Says it will check if the value is debit/credit in col M and put (-) in col K.

My question is what if we don't know that debit/credit is in col M only? What we will give instead of `RC[2]`? We Only know that header of that column will be "Debit or Credit".

My full code:

```
Rows("1:1").Select
 Selection.Find(What:="AMNT", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select

  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Noting but K2
  Range(Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(lastRow, ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[2]=""Debit"",RC[-1],IF(RC[2]=""Credit"",-RC[-1]))"
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
  Selection.Copy
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does a lot of selecting, and nothing with those selections. At the best of times it is best to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) as it slows down your code (and in most cases is unnecessary).

This code assumes the worksheet is `Sheet1`, if not change the sheet reference to suit your own Worksheet.

I create variables for all the numbers and ranges I want to use which makes the code easier to read and follow (as the variable can be descriptively named).

I find the last column in row 1 (assuming this is the header row) which means the code will work all the same if columns are added or removed.

Once the column header is found we assign the credit or debit column number to `DebtCreditColumn` and use that to define our `HeaderRange`.

We then do the same for `AMNTColumn`.

I added a couple of `If...Then` statements to display a `MsgBox` and abort the code if either values are 0 (which means the headers weren't found).

Then minus `AMNTColumn` from `DebtCreditColumn` to get the difference and assign to `FormulaReferenceColumn`.

Then find the `LastRow` in the `Debit or Credit` and set our `TargetRange` for the 'AMNT Column' from row 2 to the `LastRow` (LastRow wasn't defined in your code so I assumed it was the 'Debit or Credit' column).

Finally incorporate the `FormulaReferenceColumn` into our formula to be written to our `TargetRange`.

Like so:

```
Sub ParanTest()

Dim DebtCreditColumn As Long
Dim AMNTColumn As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim FormulaReferenceColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim HeaderRange As Range
Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim TargetRange As Range

With Sheet1
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set HeaderRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastColumn))
End With

For Each TargetCell In HeaderRange
    If TargetCell.Value Like "Debit or Credit" Then
        DebtCreditColumn = TargetCell.Column
        Exit For
    Else
        'Go To Next Cell
    End If
Next TargetCell

For Each TargetCell In HeaderRange
    If TargetCell.Value Like "AMNT" Then
        AMNTColumn = TargetCell.Column
        Exit For
    Else
        'Go To Next Cell
    End If
Next TargetCell

'In case the column can't be found, this will notify you and abort the code to avoid errors.
If DebtCreditColumn = 0 Then
    MsgBox "A column header 'Debit or Credit' could not be found.", vbOKOnly, "No column found!"
Exit Sub
End If

'In case the column can't be found, this will notify you and abort the code to avoid errors.
If AMNTColumn = 0 Then
    MsgBox "A column header 'AMNT' could not be found.", vbOKOnly, "No column found!"
Exit Sub
End If

FormulaReferenceColumn = DebtCreditColumn - AMNTColumn

With Sheet1
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, DebtCreditColumn).End(xlUp).Row    'You can define whatever column works best for you
    Set TargetRange = .Range(.Cells(2, AMNTColumn), .Cells(LastRow, AMNTColumn))
End With

TargetRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[" & FormulaReferenceColumn & "]=""Debit"",RC[-1],IF(RC[" & FormulaReferenceColumn & "]=""Credit"",-RC[-1]))"


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the code seems nothing to do with question. Or my question is weird to understand? If so please let me know. I'll try to explain in more better way. (FYI- Column K needs to be filled with the value of column J. And (-) minus sign should come before the value in column K if Column M has a value as credit.

Comment: Well your question was how to put a minus into the column K value and what if it's not Column M with credit or debit. You didn't mention anything else. Perhaps update your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Your answer works only when column K has some value already, but my formula says if col m = credit then put - and col J's value. And if col m = debit then put J's Value only.

Comment: I think I misunderstood, I apologise.

Comment: @paran I've updated my answer to fix my misunderstanding. It works more or less the same as before except now dynamically provides the difference in `RC[ ]` number for the 'Debt or Credit' column and writes the formula to the 'AMNT' column (from row 2 to the last row of Debt or Credit column). Of course you can add to it to find all relevant columns and update the formula further.